# Dotenv not loading properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I am trying to access some environment variables using `process.env` that were loaded by `dotenv`.

My folder structure :

```
.env
src
-- - server.js
```

My server.js configuration :

```
(...)
import auth from './middleware/auth'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.load({
    path: '../',
    silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
})
auth()
// Instantiate app
const app = express();
```

The file where I try to access `process.env` variable :

```
(...)
module.exports = function() {
        console.log("env", process.env.MONGODB_URI)
        var options = {};
        options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader()
        options.secretOrKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET
```

Which logs `env, undefined`, and then crashes with

`TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key`

Even if I move `.env` into `src` (same directory as server) and remove `path` in `config`, it fails.

Answer (score 8):

It appears that when you specify the path, you need to make it full:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/../.env'});
```

.env being your file

Comment: update your question and show us your folder structure, where you have the .env file and where are you trying to call it.

Comment: folder structure is the first code sample, and I'm trying to call it in `server.js` as in the 2nd code sample

Comment: If server.js is inside a subfolder my code should work. What's the output of __dirname?

Comment: `console.log(__dirname)` doesn't output anything because nothing runs in `server.js`

Comment: What do you mean? put it somewhere, if that file is being included it should output.

Comment: If I log it in `auth.js`, it outputs the right directory. If it's in `server.js`, nothing gets outputted because the app crashes before it reaches the statement

Comment: then you need to fix the error that's causing the crash first. Check the JWTStrategy and provide the needed secret.

Comment: yes that's what I'm trying to use `process.env` for, is to get that secret

Comment: Does middleware run before `server.js`? I put a log at the top of `server.js` and it gets printed after the log in `auth.js`

Comment: I don't know how's your setup. Comment out the JWT thing until you can have the env working. Debug __dirname and see what it outputs.

Comment: @iamwhitebox what exactly? The path needs to be full. Either using `__dirname` or `process.cwd()`

Comment: ```var path = require('path')``` and ```const env_path = path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/.env')``` please, don't just use string concatenation

Answer (score 5):

Try this; this should work.

```
import {} from 'dotenv/config'
import somethingElse from 'somethingElse'
...
[the rest of your code]
```

This works because of how ES6 modules imports modules.

*If you want to dig into more.* 
Please refer this. https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/

> **As a summary :**
>
> When you run a module containing an import declaration, the modules it
>   imports are loaded first, then each module body is executed in a
>   depth-first traversal of the dependency graph, avoiding cycles by
>   skipping anything already executed.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: ```import 'dotenv/config'``` should just work

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `require('dotenv').config()` on my main nodejs .js entry file and it works just fine.

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#path):

> **Path**
>
> Default: .env
>
> You can specify a custom path if your file containing environment
>   variables is named or located differently.
>
> `require('dotenv').config({path: '/custom/path/to/your/env/vars'})`

Comment: I know that your problem is probably not related to the dotenv module,
but I still gave a good answer.
Your app probably crashes because something else.

Comment: Your answer is a link to docs. That was the first thing I read. It's not a good answer sry

Comment: My answer **includes** a link to the documentation, this is how answers should be in stackoverflow.
If your problem was an error thrown because of something else, you should at least mention it, and not just open a new question.

Comment: Your answer literally paraphrases docs. The only non-doc sentences are the ones introducing the docs. Furthermore the next question I asked has nothing to do with this one. Look at the comments to this question to understand the difference before flagging as duplicate.

Comment: I'm not allowed to ask you questions in my answer.
That's what was possible to answer to you with the minimal information you presented.
Not going to make this any longer.

Answer (score 0):

use may use:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: require('find-config')('.env') })
```

This will recurse parent directories until it finds a .env file to use.

You can also alternatively use this module called [**ckey**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckey) inspired from one-liner above.

.env file from main directory.

```
# dotenv sample content
USER=sample@gmail.com
PASSWORD=iampassword123
API_KEY=1234567890
```

some js file from sub-directory

```
const ck = require('ckey');

const userName = ck.USER;     // sample@gmail.com
const password = ck.PASSWORD; // iampassword123
const apiKey   = ck.API_KEY;  // 1234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a mono-repo which uses a single `.env` file across multiple packages/work-spaces you can use the following to find the root `.env` file.

Install the find-up package from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-up

```
import find from 'find-up';

export const findEnv = () => find.sync(process.env.ENV_FILE || '.env');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the `dotenv` configs at the very top level of your app:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.load({
    path: '../',
    silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
})
(...)
import auth from './middleware/auth'

auth()
// Instantiate app
const app = express();
```

The order of imports in this case matters since you are loading the environment variables.